# Libreoffice Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

I have been using LibreOffice since Xmas, now it won't start.
I think something chunked with my attempt to edit a PDF file.
I have removed and reinstalled it from Ubuntu Software Center.
The center says it's there but nothing comes up.
I have deleted it and attempted to reinstall it with apt-get, again nothing.
Removing everything that has "libreoffice" and reinstalling it does not work.
I tried to install LibreOffice 5.0 but still nothing.
Help!

Comment: Try running `lowriter` from a Terminal window and post the Terminal output in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using synaptic package manager?

enter:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove libreoffice --purge
```

to completely remove it from your system, all traces,

then try reinstalling it with synaptic or apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```